# Is it possible to use Apache Maven Wrapper to standardize build environments?

Tags: maven, build, wrapper, environment

Can Apache Maven Wrapper be used to unify all the build environments?

Reference Link - https://maven.apache.org/wrapper/

Build environments like dev, qa, stage

If it can't be used please specify the reason, is there any other alternative for it?

Thank you

Comment: Beeing more specific might be useful to get an answer

Comment: There should not be "Build environment like dev, qa" in the first place. Build the artifact once, then stage the unchanged artifact through dev, qa, prod.